# Does QItemSelectionModel store the order of selection

Tags: c++, qt

So I use QItemSelectionModel::selectedRows to get my selection. However, it seems that the order of the selection is dependant on the order in which the user selected it first.

Example:
If I have rows 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10

Test case:
I select first row 5 then row 1, then row 2.

Then I call the QItemSelectionModel::selectedRows(); The QModelIndexList will contain the contents as per the order of selection, respectively, (5,1,2). However I wouldn't really assume that it should have an arbitrary order, rather the order relative to the row number like: (1,2,5).

Is there something I am doing wrong? Do I have to specify somewhere to get it in an ascending order of row count(1,2,5) instead of (5,1,2)?

Comment: `QItemSelectionModel::selectedRows()` does not specify the order. If you need specific order you need to sort the output yourself.

Comment: I guessed that, but just wanted to know if this is explicitly specified somewhere?

Comment: @deathNode No, it's not specified for `selectedRows` in [reference](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qitemselectionmodel.html). However it's is explicitly said for [`selectedIndexes`](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qitemselectionmodel.html#selectedIndexes).